# What does an incorrectly overridden method do?

Tags: java

Say if I'm trying to override a method but incorrectly put in a new sig, such as

```
public boolean equals(Circle o)
```

what does this method actually do? How could I call it?

Comment: You're not overriding it but overloading it.

Comment: You call it like any other method...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza consider answer it as the correct one!

Comment: Don't edit the question so that it doesn't make sense anymore, just because you got it, doesn't mean it won't be useful to others. Please accept one of the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not overriding, you are overloading. If you want to override, you should use `@Override`

```
class A {
    int x;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(A a) {
        return this.x == a.x;
```

Then the compiler would let you know that you're not really overriding anything.

If you did mean to override it, remove the `@Override` and call it just like any other method

```
MyCls cls = new MyCls();
cls.equals(new Circle())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically overloading the superclass's method in your class. You can call it like any other method, in your case by passing a `Circle` object to the `equals` method